# Change element's background color with gradient to background color without gradient

Tags: html, css

[**I have a table**](https://jsfiddle.net/alej27/90ewvq8q/) with two columns and multiple rows. When you click on any cell (and you keep the click down) except the ones that are heading, the background color changes from very light gray to light blue, and when you release the click it goes back to its original color. (*Please check the code and click a cell, now*). So far it's perfect.

```css
table {
  margin-right: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
table td {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #EEE 50%, #1F7DE2 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
table td:active {
  background-position: left bottom;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="title">
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="title">
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p style="background-color: #EEE;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #EEE); padding: 2em; display: block; border: 1px solid #C3C3C3; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
  The background should actually be like this
</p>
```

However, if you look at the method I used to change that background color was by actually using a `linear-gradient`. So, the cells already have the blue background, it's just it isn't visible, until you click them, which changes the `background-position`, pushing the gray background (and giving instead the idea that it's changing).

If you look at the end of the code, you can see there's an additional `p` element, with the background liner gradient colors I want the cells to have (two colors, up to bottom).

The problem is, with my method I guess you can't change the `background: linear-gradient` to a `background-color` (solid, with no gradient).

Comment: You mean you want to see that normally your table cells show two color up to bottom and when you active it become blue color right ?

Comment: Yes. It's a two-gradient background in its normal state, and when you click it it's one color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two gradients one under the other like so:

```
table td {
    width:100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    background: grey;
    /* Old browsers */
    background-image: 
      linear-gradient(to left,transparent 50%, #1F7DE2 50%), 
      linear-gradient(#F7f7f7, #EEE);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```css
table {
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
table td {
    width:100px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    background: grey;
    /* Old browsers */
    background-image: 
      linear-gradient(to left,transparent 50%, #1F7DE2 50%), 
      linear-gradient(#F7f7f7, #EEE);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
}
table td:active {
    background-position:left bottom;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="title">
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="title">
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked. Now the code is update. Now, I have to figure out a way to change the whole row's color on mouse click, no matter which cell of the row you click.

Answer (score -1):

How about this? it is not perfect, but could work...

https://jsfiddle.net/1uraqyqu/

```
.test{
  padding: 11px 16px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #EEE);
}
.test:active{
    background-image: none;
}
```

and html

```
<td><div class="test">Content 1</div></td>
```